# Add class to Parents <a> tag. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, parent-child

Hi I was wondering how I could add an class to my parents `<a>` tag.

I get this by using wp_list_pages():

```
<a href="http://localhost/?page_id=354">Link</a>
```

But I want it to display like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/?page_id=354" class="navA">Link</a>
```

And I want this only on my Parents `<a>` tag not on the childrens.
Thanks!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11821/class-parent-for-wp-list-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom walker to extend wp_list_pages.

custom walker in functions.php

```
class My_Custom_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_el (&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {

    $link = get_permalink($item->ID);
    $title = $item->post_title;
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<li>\n<a href='".$link."' class='navA'>".$title."</a>";

  }

  function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent</li>\n";
  }
}
```

Initialize and walker and use it, where you want call.

```
<?php
// Call class:
$My_Walker = new My_Custom_Walker();

$args = array(
    'walker'      => $My_Walker
);

wp_list_pages( $args );

?>
```

Reference Link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

also you can use hooks to achieve it.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42701/how-to-hook-wp-list-pages

Answer (score -1):

If you wrap all of these links in a div, e.g.:

```
<div id="pages-wrapper"><?php wp_list_pages(); ?></div>
```

You can then use jQuery `addClass()` as follows:

```
$('div#pages-wrapper a').addClass('navA');
```

Also, there is an area for WordPress-related questions on StackExchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please leave a comment for -1s.